# Gretty / Jetty fails to load WebAppContext with java 11, Jetty 9.4.14, gretty

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, resteasy, gretty

I try to use :

- Java 11
- RestEasy 4.1.0.Final
- Jetty 9.4.19.v20190610
- gretty-gradle-plugin from https://raw.github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin

With the following subproject build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

gretty {
    jacocoEnabled false
}

war{
    archiveName project.name+".war"
}

gretty {
  servletContainer = 'jetty9.4'
  httpPort = 8081
}

dependencies {
    [...]
    grettyRunnerJetty94 group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-runner', version: '9.4.19.v20190610'
}
```

But when I try to run my server using : `gradlew clean build runApp` I get the following exception :

```
14:53:16 WARN  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher defines neither @WebServlet.value nor @WebServlet.urlPatterns
14:53:16 WARN  Failed startup of context o.a.g.JettyWebAppContext@26a94fa5{PEPS,/peps-api-server,file:///home/isinc/devel/enercal/peps-api/server/build/inplaceWebapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.LinkBuilderImpl can not implement javax.ws.rs.core.Link$Builder, because it is not an interface (javax.ws.rs.core.Link$Builder is in unnamed module of loader org.akhikhl.gretty.FilteringClassLoader @20921b9b)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:670) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:639) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:545) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:72) ~[gretty-runner-jetty94-2.3.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:87) ~[na:na]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28) ~[na:na]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:37) ~[na:na]
        at nc.enercal.gcf.peps.ServiceGuiceServletConfig.contextInitialized(ServiceGuiceServletConfig.java:30) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:959) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:924) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:365) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:854) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy:44) ~[gretty-runner-jetty94-2.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.19.v20190610.jar:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle$start$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerManager.startServer(JettyServerManager.groovy:48) ~[gretty-runner-jetty-2.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:121) ~[gretty-runner-2.3.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) ~[groovy-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:48) ~[gretty-runner-2.3.0.jar:na]
14:53:16 INFO  Jetty 9.4.14.v20181114 started and listening on port 8081
```

And the server did not load my Servlet...

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution ?

Comment: I see that LinkBuilderImpl declaration in package `org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl` is 
`LinkBuilderImpl implements Link.Builder` (jaxrs 3.1.4) but looking at Link from package `javax.ws.rs.core` (javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m11) indeed Link.Builder is declared as :  `public static class Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Getty libs dependency in my **buildscript** method of master *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
        maven {
            url mirrorRepoUrl
        }
   }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}
```

this should add the Gretty libs only for Gradle CL, if you are using grettyRunnerJetty94 the lib is available in server runtime, but it isn't included in build for WAR (which was exactly what I looked for, so I like to thank you).